# Possible to Extract out Silktest Keywords

Tags: automated-testing, uiautomation, export, silktest, keyword-driven

Starting up on a Project again, which in its 1st phase the PM agreed us Testers will be using Silk test(never asked just told) Long story short we were able to automate a large part of the application under test before the the Plug was pulled on the Project.

Round 2 we are now using another testing Tool (which we are much happier about)
Has anyone been able to extract out automated test cases from Silk Test? If we can Extract these out and use them in the New tool this would save us a heap of time instead of redoing them completely in the new  test Tool.

Comment: It depends on the new tool. It is possible to export test cases from Silk test.

Comment: Thanks Yu Zhang. Looks like we will be using Tosca pending the POC. Cant Find anything online advising that i can get the Data from Silk and or that Tosca can use silk test data